# Webpack-dev-server injects bundle in HTML page, but nothing is rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I run webpack-dev-server (Command: "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --progress --hot"), my bundle is injected into the html page, but nothing is rendered.

Webpack.config.js file:

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    devtool: "cheap-eval-source-map",
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'App.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        inline: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'),
            hash: true,
        })
    ]
}
```

Index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

App.js file:

import React from 'react';

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h1>React Starter App</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The thing is if I change App.js to:

```
alert("test");
```

It will display the alert on the page.

Comment: What does your `index.html` file look like? Do you have an element with id `app`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `webpack.config.js`, change your entry point to `index.js` instead of `App.js` since `index.js` handles your initial rendering:

```
// webpack.config.js      
entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js');
```

The alert in `App.js` was being displayed because `App.js` was still getting bundled. However, it wasn't being rendered as the render logic in `index.js` wasn't being bundled and executed by webpack.

Comment: This along with adding <div id="app"></div> to my index.html fixed my problem. Thank you so much!